# Fetching and Caching Images in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, browser-cache

Our Web app is an image viewing platform that allows users upload imagery and track them along with map box. We have large datasets that are stored in sequences which the user can iterate through and view. I use this function to fetch and cache the images in a selected sequence so iterating through images isn't so laggy:

```
    let urlsToFetch = [];
    for (let feature in rawData.features) {
      if (rawData.features[feature].properties.url)
        urlsToFetch.push(rawData.features[feature].properties.url);
    }
    for (let u in urlsToFetch) {
      fetch(urlsToFetch[u]);
    }
  };
```

Then I use a useEffect to check if the sequence is selected and if it is fetch the images:

```
    if (selectedSequence) {
      fetchImages();
    }
  }, [selectedSequence]);
```

The problem I'm having is checking if the cache exists and if it does throw that data instead of fetching more. As of right now, every time I click off the sequence and then back on the same sequence it fetches the data again which is using a lot of memory. Also, how to delete the cache after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Hi, welcome! how are you rendering this images?

Comment: Hi @lissettdm thank you for the reply. We fetch the image from an S3 bucket and then render them in with a component with CSS. This is what we do ```let imageViewer;
  if (!selectedPicture || !selectedPicture.panoramic) {
    imageViewer = <Image src={selectedPicture.url} />```
The selectedPicture.url is the same as the S3 bucket url

Comment: the cache should work if it's enable in your browser. I don't see any thing wrong here

Comment: @lissettdm the cache is working. The problem i'm having is its not checking if it's already cached or not so every time I click on a sequence it fetches the data even if it already has it.